# How to update the UI in real-time using Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I am developing an application which will actively read from a file and analyze and display information in that file to the UI in real time.

Everything I have read tells me I should use some kind of threading to do this. I have explored background workers and also tried creating a separate thread at run time and using that thread to update all of the UI elements.

The problem comes in when I can't (or shouldn't) be making cross thread calls, as the original UI elements were created on a different thread.

Is there a way to create these UI elements on the thread that will be updating them? What is the best way to do this?

edit: There was a reply to this post (which is now gone) explaining how I should do this. After updating my code with the method described
This is the updated code I have used. Everything is fine until I add in the file system watcher. As soon as I add that I get the same error about not making cross thread calls.

Session is a class I created that parses through the log file

```
private Session s1 = new Session("");
private FileSystemWatcher fsw;
private OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();

private BackgroundWorker bgw;

private bool logActive = false;

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw.ProgressChanged += HandleProgressChanged;
    bgw.DoWork += HandleDoWork;

    fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"H:\Logs", "*.txt");
    fsw.SynchronizingObject = this;
    fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size;
    fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_OnChanged);
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd1.Filter = "log files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd1.FilterIndex = 2;
    ofd1.RestoreDirectory = true;
}

private void fsw_OnChanged(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

// this runs on the UI thread
// here's where you update the UI based on the information from the event args
private void HandleProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = s1.previousLineNumber; i < s1.GetMessageCount(); i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem((s1.GetMessage(i).date).ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(s1.GetMessage(i).type.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(s1.GetMessage(i).data);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}

// this runs on a background thread; you cannot modify UI controls here
private void HandleDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    s1.ParseLiveFile();
    bgw.ReportProgress(100);
}
```

Comment: The best way is by using delegates to access the main thread conrols. It is easy and described many times on the stackoverflow. Search a little bit and I'm sure you'll find useful answers.

Comment: There is one fundamental flaw in your approach: You manipulate the UI from additional thread(s) and do the actual work/logic (e.g. data analysis) in the "foreground" thread. However, most UI frameworks require just the opposite: Do the work in a background thread, and update the UI from one single foreground thread (the "UI thread").

Comment: Unfortunately, this is now beyond my immediate knowledge area, but I can tell you the general direction of the solution: use one of the many thread pool libraries to launch tasks for each change to the filesystem. These threads will build a data structure based on the file information and then return, via a continuation, the data to the UI thread, which can then populate the controls.

Comment: The above code is now working. I just needed to add `fsw.SynchronizingObject = this;` So that the filesystemwatcher was using the same thread as the main form.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the UI you should use Invoke or BeginInvoke.

```
void LengthyProcessInThread()
{
   ...
   foreach(var item in file)
   {
       Invoke(delegate() {
          .. Update UI here.
       });
   }
}
```

Invoke is a method on a control, Eg. the form containing the UI.

I wish you good luck with your quest.